# Reconhecer se o usuário está usando iOS ou Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios

Estou desenvolvendo uma tela de um site, e o cliente pergunto se há a possibilidade do site reconhecer se o usuário está usando Android ou iOS.

Se estiver no Android, vai pro Google Play para baixar o app e se for iOS para a App Store. Pode ser um redirecionamento.

Se for no PC, ele abre a tela normal.

Existe essa possibilidade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Server-side, você pode checar o conteúdo do cabeçalho `user-agent`:

```
// Match user agent string with operating systems 
Windows 3.11 => Win16,
Windows 95 => (Windows 95)|(Win95)|(Windows_95),
Windows 98 => (Windows 98)|(Win98),
Windows 2000 => (Windows NT 5.0)|(Windows 2000),
Windows XP => (Windows NT 5.1)|(Windows XP),
Windows Server 2003 => (Windows NT 5.2),
Windows Vista => (Windows NT 6.0),
Windows 7 => (Windows NT 6.1),
Windows 8 => (Windows NT 6.2),
Windows NT 4.0 => (Windows NT 4.0)|(WinNT4.0)|(WinNT)|(Windows NT),
Windows ME => Windows ME,
Open BSD => OpenBSD,
Sun OS => SunOS,
Linux => (Linux)|(X11),
Mac OS => (Mac_PowerPC)|(Macintosh),
QNX => QNX,
BeOS => BeOS,
OS/2 => OS/2,
Search Bot=>(nuhk)|(Googlebot)|(Yammybot)|(Openbot)|(Slurp)|(MSNBot)|(Ask Jeeves/Teoma)|(ia_archiver)
```

([fonte](http://www.geekpedia.com/code47_Detect-operating-system-from-user-agent-string.html))

Via JavaScript, o mesmo pode ser feito checando o conteúdo parcial de `navigator.appVersion`:

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) //Windows
```

Você pode então decidir qual store utilizar com um snippet como este:

```
var playStoreUrl = "http://www.play.google.com/",
    appStoreUrl  = "http://www.itunes.com/myapp",
    platform     = navigator.platform;

if (/mac/i.test(platform))
    $("#redirect").attr("href", appStoreUrl);
else if (/linux/i.test(platform))
    $("#redirect").attr("href", playStoreUrl);
else
    // Handle the case where the OS is neither MacOS nor Linux
```

([fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931598/detecting-os-version-in-javascript-and-redirecting))

Comment: Obrigado. E como que eu faria um redirect dessa tela para algum link da App Store ou Google Play?

Comment: @FelipeStoker Eu adicionei um snippet de exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Existem scrripts prontos para fazer isso pra você.

Este site tem para quase todas as linguagens: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Basicamente é só baixar o script que você quer e já era.

**EDIT**

Não posto o código por que ele vem **minified**, senão eu postava.